# Generate BuildInfo.config for Console App

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

When I build websites using TFS Build (TFS 2013.4) I get a BuildInfo.config file with each website in the drop folder.

However I cannot seem to generate the same file for a console app. I have added such things as

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets" />
```

And

```
  <!-- Build info -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Generate the BuildInfo.config file -->
    <GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile>True</GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile>
    <!-- Include server name in build info -->
    <IncludeServerNameInBuildInfo>True</IncludeServerNameInBuildInfo>
    <!-- Include the symbols path so Visual Studio can find the matching deployed code when you start debugging. -->
    <!--<BuildSymbolStorePath>
      <path to="" symbols="">
    </BuildSymbolStorePath>-->
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Yet the file does not appear. Can someone tell me what is needed to generate the BuildInfo.config?

Comment: Why do you want to create a build manifest (BuildInfo.config file) in a console app? Usually, we set up the build process to create a build manifest (BuildInfo.config file) for web project and include this manifest with the release.

Comment: We deploy a console app in a separate folder to the website. It is executed by a Windows Server scheduled task. I use a PowerShell script to deploy the website by comparing the build info to know if it is the folder containing that web site (eg. comparing the `ProjectName` from the drop folder and the server) and if it is a newer build label. I want to use the same setup for the console app. I can see that it's intended use is for Visual Studio etc. but surely it can be output from any build, not just a web site?

Comment: I have tested both Console Application and Web Application, but proved Console Application is not able to output BuildInfo.config file. GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile is only working in Web Applications.

Comment: Any idea why? Any workaround? Is there somewhere I can complain about it more ? : )

Comment: Try to submit a UserVoice at website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BuildInfo.config only generates for WebApplication projects, but with a small tweak to your .proj files, you can include the BuildInfo.config for any project you would need it for. We generate it for all our console apps since it includes valuable information around the build and commit.

In a PropertyGroup add:

```
<GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile>true</GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile>
```

I usually only add it to the configuration that I use to release under. This then results in the file only being generated when we release the product and not for debug builds. It lives inside this PropertyGroup in our .proj files:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ReleaseBuild|AnyCPU'">
```

You also need a PropertyGroup to specify the VSToolsPath and WebProjectOutputDir if these properties does not contain any values.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
<WebProjectOutputDir Condition="'$(WebProjectOutputDir)' == ''">$(OutputPath)</WebProjectOutputDir></PropertyGroup>
```

Adding this, should result in the BuildInfo.config being generated.

If it still doesn't generate, also add the following import. Maybe just first check if the import hasn't already been done. If you import it twice, you will get a warning during the build.

```
<Import Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseBuild'" Project="$(VSToolsPath)\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.Targets" />
```

The build will default the filename as [$AssemblyName].BuildInfo.config. If you want it to be BuildInfo.config (to allow AppInsights to pick it up...), override the property BuildInfoFileName in your project or when you Build:

```
<BuildInfoFileName>BuildInfo.config</BuildInfoFileName>
```

or

```
/p:BuildInfoFileName=BuildInfo.config
```

Also note the Condition that I only import it when building a specific configuration since the ReleaseManagement target doesn't exist on developers machines...

This should set you on your way...

Comment: To get the buildInfo.config to be generated, I added everything mentioned here except the `<Import /> ` was not necessary for me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we set up the build process to create a build manifest (BuildInfo.config file) for web project and include this manifest with the release. This manifest contains information about the project, source control, and build system that were used to create a specific build. This information helps Visual Studio find the matching source and symbols after we open the web application diagnosis log to review the recorded events.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets is to enable Application Insights deployment markers in an application. Check: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/11/14/implementing-deployment-markers-in-application-insights.aspx

Comment: That is helpful to understand what it's intended use is but I want to use it for something slightly different - i've added a comment to your comment to my question.